# Display group decorators in Zend Framework

Tags: html, zend-framework

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Auth extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init() 
    {   $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
        $this->setMethod('post');


        $username = $this->createElement('text','username');
        $username->setLabel('Username:')
                 ->setRequired(true);                               

        $username->setDecorators(array(



                   'ViewHelper',

                   'Description',

                   'Errors',

                   array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))



           ));


        $password=$this->createElement('password','password');
        $password->setLabel('Password:')
                 ->setRequired(true);


                $password->setDecorators(array(



                   'ViewHelper',

                   'Description',

                   'Errors',

                   array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))



           ));




        $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');

        $file->setLabel('Select File:')

            ->setDestination(BASE_PATH . '/data/uploads')

            ->setRequired(true);

                    $file->setDecorators(array(



                   'file',

                   'Description',

                   'Errors',

                   array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))



           ));





$captcha = $this->createElement('captcha', 'captcha',
array('required' => true,
'captcha' => array(
'captcha' => 'Image',
'font' => BASE_PATH .'/fonts/Average-Regular.ttf',
'fontSize' => '24',
'wordLen' => 5,
'height' => '75',
'width' => '200',
'imgDir'=> BASE_PATH.'/images/captcha',
'imgUrl'=>'../../images/captcha/',
'dotNoiseLevel' => 50,
'lineNoiseLevel' => 5)));

$captcha->setLabel('Please type the words shown:');


                    $captcha->setDecorators(array(



                   'captcha',

                   'Description',

                   'Errors',

                   array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))



           ));

           $form = new ZendX_JQuery_Form();
$date1 = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker(
                        'date1',
                        array('label' => 'Date:')
        );

            $date1->setDecorators(array(



               'UiWidgetElement',

            'Description',

                   'Errors',

                   array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),

                   array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))



       ));

        $reg=$this->createElement('submit','submit');
        $reg->setLabel('save'); 

            $reg->setDecorators(array(



               'ViewHelper',

               'Description',

               'Errors', array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td',

               'colspan'=>'2','align'=>'center')),

               array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))



       ));

    $this->setDecorators(array(



               'FormElements',

               array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'table')),

               'Form'



       ));




        $this->addElements(array(
        $username,
        $password,
        $file,
        $captcha,
        $date1,
        $reg

        ));

        $this->addDisplayGroup(array('username', 'password','file','captcha','date1','submit'), 'login',array('legend' =>'Add User'));          



          $login = $this->getDisplayGroup('login');
        $login->setDecorators(array(

                    'FormElements',
                    'Fieldset',

                    array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'div','style'=>'width:70%;;float:left; padding-top:5px;'))
        ));

        return $this;
    }


}
?>
```

addUser.phtml

```
<?php 

echo $this->form->getDisplayGroup('login');  //This form aligned perfectly  


echo $this->form;   //This won't 

?>
```

I am new to Zend Framework, I just started playing with Zend Decorators and DisplayGroup.

Comment: what is the issue, what do you want to achieve

Comment: This can be closed as "unclear what you're asking".